# PivotItem's Header keeps Saying First

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Whenever I debug the application, no matter what I do to the PivotItem's header, it will say "first", and the Pivot's Title always says "MY APPLICATION".

Code:

**PivotPage.xaml**:

```
<Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="THE BOX" x:Name="pivot">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem1" Header="The Box" 
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

UPDATE:
I found nothing in the code-behind that influences this behavior:

**PivotPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public sealed partial class PivotPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    private readonly NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader =
        ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PivotPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="NavigationHelper"/> associated with this <see cref="Page"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }

    private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Save the unique state of the page here.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the list when the app bar button is clicked.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Box = Note.MakeTable();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property_name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
        }
    }

    #region NavigationHelper registration

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    #endregion

    private void MakeTable(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Box = Note.MakeTable();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Box = Note.MakeTable();
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: That's weird! There is no code in the code behind of the PivotPage.xaml? Sure it's that page that get's loaded, you deleted the default MainPage.xaml and changed the startup in the app.xaml.cs?

Comment: I'll check one more time, but I'm pretty sure there wasn't anything related to this is the code-behind.

Comment: @Depechie: Nope. nothing.

Comment: And there is no longer a MainPage.xaml?

Comment: @Depechie: No. This isn't WPF; this is Windows-Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove **[x:Uid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613571(v=vs.110).aspx)** parameter from Controls to use specified text.

Or modify the value in **[Resources.resw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx)** file.

Comment: Yep that could also be the case if resources are used :)

Comment: @Roman: Why would that be, if I'm declaring it here? Or better yet, what does x:Uid do in relation to Resources.resw?

Comment: Nevermind. Clicked the links. That nailed it. Thanks! PivotPage Templates play with you by adding all this extra stuff on startup of a new Project.